# Программирование vga видеоадаптера, assembler

Tags: ассемблер, graphics, vga

Что делает этот код?

```
SC_INDEX = 03C4h
SC_MAPMASK = 2

mov dx,SC_INDEX
mov ax,SC_MAPMASK+15*256
out dx,ax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код разрешает запись во все четыре "memory plane", не знаю как это будет по русски. Младшие 8 бит AX - индекс, биты 8-11 для индекса 2 - битовая маска этих самых plane.
Источник - http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware

PS. Но вообще беглое гугление по вашему коду выдает исходники с комментариями где примерно это же и написано...